# Visual Studio 2010 double-click to select whitespace is too aggressive

Tags: visual-studio-2010, whitespace, selection, double-click

In Visual Studio 2008 double clicking in a large section of whitespace would select all the contiguous whitespace only.  Now I am using Visual Studio 2010 and double clicking in a large section of whitespace selects the word preceding and the word following the whitespace as well.  This makes cleaning up large sections of whitespace more difficult (for alignment or other reasons). Is there a setting or way to get the older behavior?

Comment: I can't even reproduce the behaviour in VS2010...

Comment: After your comment I looked on a second machine I have and found it does not have the problem.  I believe the only difference is I have the productivity power tools installed on the one that has the problem.

Comment: I just started having a similar issue where double-clicking on a word selects the space on either end and part of the adjacent words.  Very frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is killing me... glad I'm not the only one. Misery loves company. Anyway, here's a couple of links of MS acknowledging the issue, and a MS feedback post about it. Bottom line, they "may" try to fix it for the next version of VS. Ouch. It's on the Won't Fix list. The work around is a joke. I hope someone figures out a better fix or work around.

[Acknowledgment of issue](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vseditor/thread/60225a64-3ac8-46f2-b52e-500b24ff595a)

[Feedback post](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/573567/visual-studio-2010-c-editor-whitespace-delete#details)

Answer (score 0):

This sort-of circumvents the question, but you can do `Ctrl+E+D` to format the document or `Ctrl+E+F` for format the selection (which removes the need to select any whitespace).

Comment: I am familiar with these options but we have some very unusual company formatting rules and our formatting must essentially be all done manually; but this selection issue applies in other places too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the shortcut `MAJ + HOME` to reproduce the desired behaviour.  I know it makes you use the keyboard, but you get used to it, and sometimes it's even helpful.

I know its not really a real solution but I can't write comments yet.